# User logout after refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase authentication. After authentication when refresh the page user is logged out.

I have this in my index.js file but it doesn't work.

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION);
```

Comment: That should persist the state in sessionStorage. Reload of the same tab/window should persist the user. If you open a new tab/window, you would be considered signed out. Are you sure you are reloading the same tab? Also make sure you wait for the returned promise to resolve before reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you need to store the session. It's really common save sessions at **localstorage**.

Actually it have a lot of implementation of packages to control this things and make this transparent for you. But in the practice you need to find some way to store the session and when the page reloads you need to verify if the session that you have stored is valid.

Read about this. Some good references: [Where to Store Tokens](https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens), [Session Storage and Local Storage in React](https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react/)